# Logstash- file input adds escaping

Tags: escaping, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I would like to disable escaping when receiving events from a file.
For instance, here is the event (input is a file):
**a=\"hello\" b=\"world\"**
This is the output:
**a=\\"hello\\" b=\\"world\\"\r"**

While using other inputs such as tcp, udp, no escaping is being added.

How to disable and remove the escaping? Is there a generic solution for that?  codec/plugins and not a fix in the filter itself?

I prefer not using: msg.gsub! ('\"', '"')
Thanks:)